# Azure SSL Configuration

Tags: azure, ssl

I created, through a third party (StartSSL), an SSL certificate for my Azure website. I was able to upload it, but when I surf to the site I get security warnings about obsolete security algorithms and the like.

The domain is elect.olbert.com. Can someone explain to me what I need to do to fix these problems? I'm new to Azure and, frankly, the documentation there is not all that accessible.

Comment: A great tool for this stuff is [SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=elect.olbert.com).  I'm guessing the obsolete security algorithm to which you refer is it bitching about the RC4 cipher suite support.  Is your "Azure website" just a hosted Windows Server machine running IIS?  If so, I can post a formal answer with how to change the IIS cipher suites.  If Azure offers some other hosting, you'll need input from someone else on how to change it.

Comment: "...but when I surf to the site I get security warnings..." From what?  I just pulled it up in IE, Chrome, and Firefox, and did not see any such warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Qualys SSL labs to get a detailed report about your SSL configuration:

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=elect.olbert.com

In this case, the report lists 2 weak cipher suites, both related to the RC4 cipher. This is now considered insecure and you are recommended to disable it.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4

According to Microsoft, at the time of writing this answer (June 2015) it is not possible to change the cipher suites on Azure Websites because they are controlled at the guest OS level and the OS is shared on Azure websites. Many people have asked for this feature though and they are estimating that it will be in production from mid July 2015

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/50f1ab33-c22a-4629-951e-b7510f6b2cbe/upgrading-tlsssl-cryptography-for-azure-web-apps?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview

If you can wait until then, and they deliver on time, you should be OK. If you can't wait, or if there are problems that cause them to delay the push to production, then you will need to change your hosting. Note: In general, you should expect to get less control over these sorts of things with Azure WebSites. That is part of the trade-off that they offer of low maintenance vs. reduced control.

If you want to stay on Azure, you can use a WebRole instead of Azure WebSites. This gives you the control you need, but it will be more expensive.

Answer (score 0):

At https://elect.olbert.com/Account/Login I can see warning about not secure certificate, because it - or any parent certificate in chain! - use SHA1 for signature - this is no longer considered safe. See here :

https://konklone.com/post/why-google-is-hurrying-the-web-to-kill-sha-1

This is not issue with Azure, but wrong (obsolete technology) certificate. Just get new one with SHA256 or better.

Answer (score -1):

Let's Encrypt's certificates, which are also free, are currently getting an A grade from Qualys SSL Labs on Azure Web Apps.

You could try switching over to them, but that requires using [the "Azure Let's Encrypt" site extension](http://www.siteextensions.net/packages/letsencrypt) to handle configuring IIS.

Let's Encrypt has an unusual model when compared to other certificate authorities. Acquiring a certificate from them is done in an entirely automated fashion, and you have to renew your certificates much more frequently - which is what the site extension makes easy.

There are several steps required to get the certificate in place, but I've put together a [full step-by-step write up](https://gooroo.io/GoorooTHINK/Article/16420/Lets-Encrypt-Azure-Web-Apps-the-Free-and-Easy-Way/) that walks you through them.

Comment: Just linking to your own library (or utility) is not a good answer. Linking to it, explaining why it solves the problem, providing code using it to do so and disclaiming makes for a better answer. See: [How can I link to an external resource in a community-friendly way?](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94022/)